# Short circuit vs circuit with load

Tags: electric-circuits, short-circuits

I'm studying about short circuit phenomenal. From the information I have searched, given a small battery (AAA), if we connect the 2 poles of the battery directly with a wire, without load (i.e. the light bulb), the circuit is short.

If there is a load, the circuit isn't short.

Could you please explain me why if there is a load, the circuit is not short ? Is it because of the resistence of the load ? Can you tell me the resistence of the light bulb is often how much Ohm and the resistence of the wire is how much Ohm ?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Strictly speaking, one should not say, "short circuit," if there is no "load." What it _really_ means is, that there is a low resistance path (usually caused by accident, but maybe done on purpose) that allows current to bypass the load--allows the current to take a short cut from the one terminal of the power supply back to the other terminal without going through the load. But more loosely speaking, people also will say "short circuit" or "shorted out" when the terminals of a power supply are connected together even when there is no "load" present.

Comment: P.S., "Short circuit" usually implies a very low resistance connection, but there is no specific number of Ohms (or milliohms).

Comment: Hi, i have a naive question please. If there is a short cut and a normal path which are parallel, the current will only flow through the short cut (i.e. no electric current on the normal path) or there will be electric current in both path ? and why ? please help me!

Comment: You'll have current in both paths, but the current in each path will be inversely proportional to the resistance in each. If the "short circuit" path has 1/1000 the resistance of the load path, then the short circuit path will get 1000 times the current. But note! Not every "load" is a simple resistor. The _apparent_ resisistance of an "active" load that has diodes, transistors, etc. may depend on the voltage; and the voltage may depend on how the short circuit affects the power supply. Predicting the current through an active load when there is a short circuit could be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

A theoretical short circuit has zero resistance.
In practice connecting across the supply terminals something which has a resistance much lower than the lowest specified resistance is called a short circuit.
In the UK the voltage is $230\,\rm V$ and the maximum current rating of a socket is $13\,\rm A$ which corresponds to a load of $230/13 \approx 20\,\Omega$.
Thus if one joined the live and the neutral with anything which had a resistance much lower than $20\,\Omega$ you might call that a short circuit.
A $230\,\rm V$ mains incandescent light bulb rated at $100\,\rm W$ has a resistance of $230^2/100 \approx 500\,\Omega$ which certainly would not short circuit the supply.
One way of protecting a circuit against a short circuit is to introduce in series a fuse which will melt if the current passing through it is above some specified value and hence stop the flow of electric current.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, it is clear. I see that people calculate the resistence by using Voltage and the current. But in practice, i think that the resistence existes already "a priori" to any connection to the energy source, right ? I'm a little bit confused whether we can say "the resistence depends on the voltage and the current" or not when it seems to me that it exists already. Can you help me to clarify this ? Thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge If you define resistance $R=V/I$ then for a light bulb the resistance increases as the current and voltage increases because the filament of the bulb gets hotter. If the resistance of a cold light bulb is measured it would be very much less than $500\,\Omega$.

Comment: Hi, so in which way should I think about it please ? It is better to think of the resistence as "a priori" or "a posteriori" ?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question.

Comment: Ah, i mean that it is better to understand that the resistence depends on the Voltage and current or it should be understood that normally the resistence is known beforehand ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you have short circuit when the poles of a generator are connected with no loads in between.

Given a simple circuit of a load $R$ connected to the poles of a tension generator with potential $E$, Ohm's law and Kirchhoff circuit law gives you the electric current in the circuit,

$$i = \frac{E}{R} \ .$$

Multiplying by potential difference by current, you get the power provided by generator and dissipated by the load, as

$$P = E \, i = \frac{E^2}{R} \ ,$$

so that it's easy to realize that $P \propto R^{-1}$ for a given $E$. And, as $R \rightarrow 0$, $P \rightarrow \infty$.
As the power goes to infinity, the mathematical linear model may fail to describe your system, while the load can start burning.

The resistance of an incandescent lightbulb could be approximately $10÷100 \, \Omega$.

The resistance of a wire of length $L$, section of area $A$ and material with resistivity $\rho$ can be approximately evaluated as

$$R = \rho \frac{L}{A} \ .$$

Good conductors have resistivity $\rho \sim 10^{-8} \Omega m$, as you can find here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity. Thus, as an example, a wire with section $A = 1\, mm^2$, has resistance per meter equal to $\frac{R}{L} = 10^{-2} \Omega \, m^{-1}$.

Comment: Then I think that good conductor can cause short-circuit ? given that short-circuit is the fact that the electric current is flows through "nearly" zero resistence ? Am I right ?

Comment: more or less, you're right

Comment: I see that the resistence of the light bulb you mentionned above is quite small (0.1 Ohm), why is there no short circuit in this case ? Can you explain me ? Thankss

Comment: The resistance of a lightbulb is $\approx 10 - 100 \Omega$. The resistance of $0.1 \Omega$ is the one of a wire of $1 \, m$ length and area $1 \, mm^2$.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm studying about short circuit phenomenal. From the information I
> have searched, given a small battery (AAA), if we connect the 2 poles
> of the battery directly with a wire, without load (i.e. the light
> bulb), the circuit is short.

A "short" means zero resistance. With the exception of superconductors, a wire does not have zero resistance. So placing a wire across the battery is not a "short circuit". That said, "wires" in circuit analysis, unless otherwise specified, are considered to have resistance negligible to the rest of the circuit, so that they are assigned a resistance of zero.

> Can you tell me the resistance of the light bulb is often how much Ohm
> and the resistence of the wire is how much Ohm ?

Again, the resistance of a "wire" would generally be considered much less than that of a light bulb so that it is considered to be zero Ohms.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A short in a circuit is two points in that circuit connected by an arbitrarily low resistance.  There are really two ways "short" is used.  The first is simply when you connect two points with a wire, making the voltage difference between them zero.  Then there's the problematic one, where you connect two points with a wire which are being *held* at different voltages.  A short across a battery is a problematic short because one end must be 1.5V higher than the other, but it's just a wire.  An idealized wire can't have a voltage drop across it.

In the problematic case, a short implies that the actual behavior of the circuit depends on higher order effects that aren't being modeled.  Things like internal resistances of batteries (AAA have an internal resistance of somewhere around 0.1 ohm to 1.0 ohm, in series with the load), or the temperature of the wire, or electromagnetic interference start to play a major part in the behavior of the circuit.  If I replace the 1.5V source with a laboratory bench voltage source with a very low internal resistance, I might burn out a circuit that would have held just fine with a mere AAA power it.

The line is not cut and dry.  One cannot say "0.1 ohm is a load, but 0.099ohm is a short."  There is indeed a middle ground where the result of the circuit is some balance between the desired "ideal" behavior being modeled and the higher order effects.  If the internal resistance of a battery is 1 ohm, and I attach a 1 ohm load to it, that wont be quite a short.  It's not entirely dependent on those higher order effects.  But you'll get the wrong answer if you ignore them.  In that particular case, the current in the circuit might be as little as a half of what you calculate in the ideal case.

Usually when we choose to use the word "short," it has crossed a line where it is *very* clear that we have crossed through that muddy region.  If you "short" a battery, it is very clear that the dynamics of the system is based on thing you aren't modeling.

And again, this is all based on the problematic definition of "short."  We'll also use the same word to describe non-problematic bridging of two points with wires.  As an example, a switch "shorts" its two contacts when closed.  We may design a circuit so that this is not a problem (in fact, in the case of a light switch, it's very desirable!).

In such settings, sometimes the creator of a circuit will specify a maximum resistance that will be called a "short."  As an example, one might have a circuit to detect the presence of an object.  If the object is present, it shorts the circuit.  If it is not present, the circuit is open.  One might find a datasheet says that if the object is present, then it needs to make sure a resistance is <= 20 ohms, but if it is not present, then it needs to make sure a resistance is >= 1 megaohm.  In the range between 20 ohms and 1 megaohm, the behavior of the circuit may not be easy to model, but in the extreme short and extreme open cases, it is easy to see what will happen.